# Can 2 different species do a dance fusion and work?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z, dragon-ball-super

In episode 88th of Dragon Ball Super, in one subtitled version

> Gohan asks Piccoro why dont they try a technique of fusion together. Note: this could be a bad translation because in another subtitled version he doesnt say exactly the same

So my question is , can 2 different species in Dragon Ball do a fusion dance and work? We know a fusion between 2 different people can work with the Potara earrings (for example a supreme kai and a witch) but what about fusion with the fusion dance? will something like that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is : it depends.

In the manga, it was stated that there are certain requirements to the Fusion Dance as opposed to the Potara Earring fusion, such as the mergers need to have equal power and roughly similar height, but in recent interview, Akira Toriyama said that it is possible to merge no matter the conditions, as long as it all goes well and it is even possible for a larger number of people to merge.

Source : http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Fusion